Is there a method of sending FormData in http POST request in Ionic while CapacitorHttp is enabled?
I am trying to upload an image to Cloudinary from an Ionic IOS app. I am sending the file using FormData but CapacitorHttp is enabled in the app in order to deal with CORS issues. However, FormData does not work with CapacitorHttp.
I have tried using fetch API, as well as Axios and also Angular HttpClient, but all http requests go through CapacitorHttp.
So I would like to know if there is a way to make this post request containing FormData that bypasses the CapacitorHttp just for this one request, or if there is another way I can go about this.

as per documentation you can pass dataType: 'formData' in HttpOptions : https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http#httpoptions

use CapacitorWebFetch:
await CapacitorWebFetch("<url>", {
  body: formData
})

CapacitorWebFetch is fetch native
